# Get WildFly/Keycloak datasources pool statistics via JMX

Tags: jmx, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak 3.4.3.Final version in domain mode.
And I can obtain DataSources statistics (like ActiveCount,AviableCount,..)
from WildFly management console.

But when I connect remotely via JMX to some cluster node using JConsole,
MBeans tab of JConsole doesn't  contain information about pool statistics-
only some static information about configuration is shown 
in jboss.as/auth-server-clustered/datasources item

Is it possible to get this statstics via JMX?